# Родовий відмінок множини слів на -шшя, -жжя, -ччя

Tags: відмінювання, родовий-відмінок, declension

Сьогодні, коли мені треба було поставити слово «протиріччя» у фразу «жодних …», мене раптом переклинило:

- «протиріч» — [71 результат у гугл-книжках](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%96%D1%87%22), [319 результатів у гуглі](//www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%96%D1%87%22&num=100&start=300), чи
- «протирічь» — [53 результати в гугл-книжках](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%96%D1%87%D1%8C%22), [355 результатів у гуглі](//www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%96%D1%87%D1%8C%22&num=100&start=300)?

На *-ддя* все зрозуміло: «підборіддя» → «підборідь» — бо закінчення м'яке. Аналогічно *-ття*, *-ззя*, *-сся*, *-цця*, *-лля*, *-ння*. Інакше просто й бути не може.

А що ж із *-шшя*, *-жжя*, *-ччя*: *затишшя*, *бездоріжжя*, *обличчя*? З одного боку, наче не очікуєш у кінці *-шь*, *-жь*, *-чь* в українській мові (невже тут буде?). А з іншого — вони в усіх інших відмінках і формах пом'якшені на кінці (невже в родовому відмінку пом'якшення зникне?).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Коротка відповідь

- За правилами відмінювання — *протиріч*, але *підборідь*, *знань*
- Також пропонують варіант — *протиріччів*

---

### Довга відповідь

1. Що таке *«протиріччя»*? Це **іменник середнього роду** з збірним значенням узагальнення, морфологія якого містить закінчення `-я`.
2. Такі іменники відмінюються по другому типу відмінювання:
   [**Правопис закінчень відмінюваних слів** → **§ 45. Поділ на групи** → **II відміна** → **2. М’яка група**](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par45IIp2), прокрутіть до **Середній рід**:

   > До м’якої групи належать іменники середн. роду із закінченням `-е` та `-я` (без суфіксів `-ен-`, `-ят-` при відмінюванні й переважно з подовженням кінцевого приголосного основи): *горе, місце, море, поле; життя, завдання, збіжжя, здоров’я, змагання, знаряддя, листя, обличчя, пір’я, полум’я, сім’я, тім’я*.
3. Такі іменники утворюються з попереднім **подвоєнням приголосної**.

   - Окрім випадку, коли подвоєна приголосна вже є;
   - Окрім випадку, коли корінь закінчується на губну приголосну `-б, -п, -м, -ф`, а також `-р`; у цьому випадку замість подвоєння вживається апостроф: *подвір'я*
4. Окрім того, при подвоєнні відбувається зсув приголосних:

   - `-г` → `-ж`: *бі**г*** → *збі**жж**я*, *дру**г*** → *подру**жж**я*, *доро**г**а* → *бездорі**жж**я*
   - `-к` → `-ч`: *ре**к**ти* → *протирі**чч**я*, *ли**к*** → *обли**чч**я* <sub>(старовинні форми кореня ще й досі впливають на морфологію слова, хоча в чистому вигляді вже не використовуються)</sub>

**Тепер, ваше запитання важливо розділити на два:**

1. Чи подвоювати приголосну?
2. Чи вживати м'який знак?

З формальної точки зору, відмінювання утворених таким чином іменників відповідає правилам відмінювання **другої відміни, м'якої групи, середнього роду**.

> [§ 55. Родовий відмінок](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par55)
>
> У родовому відмінку множини іменники другої відміни мають закінчення `-ів (-їв)`, *нульове закінчення* та `-ей`.
>
> 1. **Закінчення `-ів`** (після голосного та апострофа `-їв`) мають іменники чол. роду та іменники середн. роду на `-е, -я`: *батьків, берегів, вольтів, героїв, друзів, дощів, країв, метрів, омів, підписів, робітників, солдатів, солов’їв, степів, товаришів, школярів; верхів’їв, відкриттів, життів, міжгір’їв, морів, нагір’їв, подвір’їв, полів, покриттів, почуттів, прислів’їв.*
> 2. **Нульове закінчення** мають усі іменники середн. роду на `-о, -е` та більшість на `-я` (переважно з попереднім м’яким подовженим приголосним `н`): *бажань, боліт, вагань, верховіть, весіль, відер, вікон, доліт, завдань, засідань, знань, кіл, кілець, коліс, місць, озер, **облич**, пальт, питань, піддаш, полотен, посилань, прізвищ, **роздоріж**, серць (і сердець), сіл, слів, сприйнять, хутер, яєць; але: морів, полів (рідше піль)*.

Тобто, **нульове закінчення** може містити або не містити м'який знак залежно від того, після якої приголосної воно ставиться.

---

### Фактичне вживання

Тут складніше, пошук по інтернету дає велику кількість посилань, де дописувачі активно сперечаються. Наприклад, [тут](http://maidan.org.ua/arch/mova/1189037030.html).

А у Бібліотеці Вернадського навіть знайшовся матеріал під красномовною назвою зі знаком оклику: [Колібаба, Л. «Подружжів і подруж, але не подружь!»](http://oai.org.ua/index.php/record/view/423874) (переглянути/скачати [тут](http://www.irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/cgi-bin/irbis_nbuv/cgiirbis_64.exe?C21COM=2&I21DBN=UJRN&Image_file_name=PDF/Ukrm_2011_4_22.pdf)). Авторка — [Лариса Колібаба](http://www1.nas.gov.ua/institutes/ium/Structure/Departments/Department3/employees/Pages/kolibaba.aspx), кандидат філологічних наук, старший науковий співробітник.

---

#### -ІВ, -ЇВ

На мою думку, спроби встановити правопис з використанням `-ів` та `-їв` спричинене перекваліфікацією цих іменників на **мішану групу вімінювання**.

Той самий сайт Правопис [містить](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm) містить іншу групу іменників на `-й`, наприклад, *вчитель*, *край*. Вони, насправді, у родовому відмінку множини отримують закінчення `-ів` та `-їв`.

Comment: «Іменник Середнього роду з збірним значенням узагальнення, морфологія якого містить **суфікс `-н-`** та закінчення -я» — це ви пишете про слово «протиріччя»...

Answer (score 7):

Це орфограма «Вживання м’якого знаку». Офіційний сайт української мови [пише](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/fonetika_i_pismo/vzhivannja_m_39_jakogo_znaka/4-1-0-27):

> М'який знак ставиться лише після букв, що позначають зубні (д, т, з, с, ц, л, н), якщо ці приголосні вимовляються м'яко: кінець, поршень, коли-небудь, ткацький, близько, просьба, бадьорий, тіньовий, спрацьований. Зокрема м'який знак пишеться:
>
> - у суфіксах -ськ-, -цьк-, -зьк-: поліський, волинський, військо, людськість, по-товариському, по-українському, зайчисько, Луцьк, Донецьк, донецький, криворізький; у суфіксах -еньк-, -оньк-, -іньк-: рученьки, гарненький, голівонька, свіжісінький.
> - Після р м'який знак пишеться тільки перед о: трьох, чотирьом, забрьоханий; а також у слові Горький (хоч вимовляється [горкий]).
> - **Після інших букв та після р в інших випадках м'який знак не ставиться: голуб, кров, верф, ніч, подорож, тепер, обличчя — облич, десятиріччя — десятиріч, буря — бур, зоря — зір, тюрма, Харків.**

Ваші слова підпадають саме під останній пункт цього правила, тому *затишшя, бездоріжжя, обличчя* в родовому відмінку множини пишуться без м’якого знаку: *затиш, бездоріж, облич*. І взагалі, українські слова на *-шь, -жь, -чь* [закінчуватися не можуть](http://ereadr.org/book/nauka_i_ucheba/10210-inversijnij-slovnik-ukrayinskoyi-movi/812).

Comment: Що таке «Офіційний сайт української мови»? Ні, я стикався раніше з таким, але, по-моєму, схоже на невдалий жарт. Мабуть, варто написато якось типу «так званий „Офіційний сайт української мови“» — бо те, як вони з маркетингових міркувань вирішили називатися, це одне — а користувача в оману (навіть невільно) вводити не варто. Чи його справді НАНУ видає і він таки справді офіційний?

Comment: @Sasha, нормальний такий **офіційний сайт** української мови, [195.216.243.145](http://195.216.243.145.ipaddress.com/). Та й [домен](http://ukrainskamova.com.websiteoutlook.com/) теж гарний :-)

Comment: Взагалі, насправді я це допер (про відсутність м'якого знака) вже давно, просто вирішив все одно написати питання — сподіваюся, це буде комусь корисно (раз у мене один раз серед ночі з голови вилетіло, то й у когось може). А що насправді цікавить зараз конкретно мене (хоча, може варто задати окреме питання чи відредагувати це) — це як воно вимовляється: як пишеться (без усілякого пом'якшення), чи все таки -ш, -ж, -ч на кінці пом'якшена (хоч і не м'яка, звісно)?

Comment: @Sasha - Твердо. Як на мене, то -ш, -ж, -ч і перед -я тверді.

Comment: @YellowSky, офіційно — вони «пом'якшені». Тобто «м'які» в українській мові вони взагалі бути не можуть, але перед -я-, -ю-, -і-, -є- — пом'якшені. А «знака пом'якшення» в укр. мові нема (то чи не можуть буть вони пом'якшеними і в цьому нульовому закінченні?).